# Is "somebody else" just as fine as "someone else"?

Tags: phrasing

I was wondering if *somebody else* and *someone else* were interchangeable, as the former rolls off the tongue better in the context I want to use it.

Can one say *somebody else*, or is *someone else* more of an established saying?

Answer (score 1):

While there is no difference in meaning, there is difference in register:

> There is *no difference in meaning* between ***someone*** and ***somebody***, but *somebody is more common in spoken English*, and *someone is more common in written English*. 
> ([Collins](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/english-usage/what-is-the-difference-between-someone-and-somebody))

> The only difference that most native speakers can agree upon is that ***someone** is more formal than **somebody*** (just as *anyone* is more formal than *anybody*, and *everyone* is more formal than *everybody*). This means that in a sentence like the one below, used in a legal context, *someone* is a much more likely choice than *somebody*.
>
> - The bank requires that the deed be signed by ***someone*** authorized by the courts.
>
> It’s also interesting to note that someone is used more frequently than somebody, according to the data that we have on language use.
> ([Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/difference-between-someone-and-somebody))

This may be the reason why [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=someone%20else%2C%20somebody%20else&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) finds ***someone else*** much more common (because it searches written texts).

However, if register is not so important for your context, *somebody else* is perfectly fine. Oscar Wilde uses it:

> They are always asking a writer why he does not write like ***somebody else***, or a painter why he does not paint like ***somebody else***, quite oblivious of the fact that if either of them did anything of the kind he would cease to be an artist.
> (*[The Miscellaneous Writings of Oscar Wilde](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Miscellaneous_Writings_of_Oscar_Wild/q09ODwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22somebody%20else%22%20Oscar%20wilde&pg=PT364&printsec=frontcover)*)